# How to trigger click event in backboon.js view in css3 style without div id or class name

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I am able to fire click event in simple way like

```
   events: {
    "click #divid1" : function1,
    "click .divid2" : function2,
            "click "+this.$el.children().eq(1): function2

},
```

Click on #id and .class name works fine, but my goal is to fire click event in css3 style. How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "css3 style"?

Comment: actually we are developing a plugin it will be embed on any website, so we don't want any #id or .class conflict. that's why we want to trigger click event in html hierarchy(like object.children().eq(1))

Answer (score 0):

Views use [`delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) to bind events and that

> Uses jQuery's `on` function to provide declarative callbacks for DOM events within a view.

That means that you can use any jQuery selector in the view's `events`. In particular, you can use [`:eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
events: {
    'click :eq(1)': 'callback_name'
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gn8uK/

Answer (score 0):

I have got another and good answers,
we can trigger events in css3 style like this

```
,events: {
       "click div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(2)" : "myfunction"
    },
 myfunction:function(){
 alert('hi');
 }
```